# Reporting All Databases with Their Collection Sizes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, size

I am trying to find every collection in every db which size is over 1GB in MongoDB and print the dbname, collection name, collection size.
I wrote a javascript for it, it works on mongo which has fewer databases but it shuts down the mongo while trying the script at production. It seems the query isn't great performance wise.

Here is the javascript i wrote:

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(dbName){
    db.getMongo().getDB(dbName).getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collName){
        var coll = db.getMongo().getDB(dbName).getCollection(collName);
        var collSize = coll.stats(1024*1024*1024).storageSize;
        if (collSize > 1) {
            print(dbName + ":" + collName + ":" + collSize);
        }
    })
})
```

Is there a way to improve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This runs from `mongosh` for server version 7.0.1:

```
var dbNames = db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true })["databases"].map(d => d.name);
for (let dbname of dbNames) {
    let colls = db.getSiblingDB(dbname).getCollectionNames();
    for(let coll of colls) {
        let stats = db.getSiblingDB(dbname)
                      .getCollection(coll)
                      .stats({ scale: 1024*1024*1024 });
        if (stats.storageSize > 1) 
            print(dbname, coll, stats.storageSize); 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when i run this script without selecting any db, it returns 0 for all dbs' collection sizes. When i change the db upon entering mongo, it returns sizes correctly.

Comment: When you start mongo shell the default database is `test`. You can know it by typing `db`. I had tried the code from the default `test` database as well as changing to another database (`use other_db`) with same results. Of course, the databases and collections I had are of small size and few dozens only -  and I had used `size = db.getCollection(coll).stats().storageSize`.

Comment: Please tell about the cluster information (MongoDB version and type of cluster). Also tell if authentication is enabled and in such case what kind of privileges the user has when running the above commands. Note that I am running the script from a standalone MongoDB v4.2.8 with authentication  _not_ enabled.

Comment: Hello, i tried it on non-cluster Mongo too, it is our test environment. As you said, the default db is test. I run the script on this Mongo too which is on 4.0.27 version, same thing. The data are all for test dbs's collections, i am gonna be posting an output as a new answer, can't do it here.  I am running mongo with --authenticationDatabase="admin" option btw

Comment: This doesn't work because `db.getCollection` refers to the default DB (`test`) instead of the current DB that is being iterated over (with name `dbName`)

Comment: @Woodz Updated the query and for server version 7.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few areas where you can improve the performance:

1. Use temporary variables to store DB and collection to avoid repeated queries to re-access them
2. Avoid `.getMongo` which returns the current connection which is already available indirectly via `db`

I have applied these changes to create this script, which has no noticable performance issues when run on a range of loaded clusters.

```
const dbNames = db.adminCommand({ listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true })["databases"].map(d => d.name);
  for (const dbName of dbNames) {
    const currentDb = db.getSiblingDB(dbName);
    currentDb.getCollectionNames().forEach(collName => {
      const coll = currentDb.getCollection(collName);
      const collSize = coll.stats(1024 * 1024 * 1024).storageSize;
        if (collSize > 1) {
            print(dbName + ":" + collName + ":" + collSize);
        }
    });
  }
```